# Moving object along a bezier curve with variable speed in Corona SDK

Tags: box2d, coronasdk, bezier

I am developing a game like paper toss using Corona SDK but in my game there is power factor which determines the velocity of object. Now I want to move my object along the bezier curve created by first touch to object, angle of object, wind speed and power.  Everything is working but I am unable to move the object with variable speed. Please let me know how I should move the object with velocity vary according to power. Or can it be done by using physics only. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code to help understand better and help you in a descent manner?

Answer (score 0):

You could use physics, yes - but for bezier curves in Corona you can't beat this post/code; http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2010/12/12/bezier-curves-corona-source-code

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2010/12/12/bezier-curves-corona-source-code

This is image moving along with Bezier curve.